# Setup single CLI to interface with multiple containers?

Tags: shell, docker, docker-compose

I'm not a Docker expert and have been struggling with this problem for a few hours now -

I have 2 independent images - one for a Python REPL and another for a Scheme REPL. I want to create an application that provides a single CLI interface wrapped around 2 containers running either image - so that when I enter `python` it connects to the Python REPL container and executes everything that follows there; whereas, `scheme` connects to the Scheme REPL container.

I have 2 questions -

a) Is this possible at all using Docker Compose? Also, does this really qualify as a use case for Docker Compose?

b) Suppose I start with the following bare-bones `docker-compose.yml` -

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    python:
        image: "python:3.6.2-alpine3.6"
    racket:
        image: "m4burns/racket"
```

Do I setup the common CLI (say a bash shell) in another container that communicates with the other two if I issue the python or scheme command? How do I define the entrypoints?

I know a simpler solution would simply be to make a Dockerfile that combines both the Python & Scheme setup into a single image. However, I really want to keep them separate and hence am going down this path.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using docker-compose does not provide you a single CLI interface. Instead, two separate containers are created but advantage is that different containers can communicate with each other using service name that you specify.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    python:
        image: "python:3.6.2-alpine3.6"
    racket:
        image: "m4burns/racket"
```

From the example you gave, `python` can access `racket` by using http://racket. The containers can access each other using their service name. By default, service name is treated  as hostname. And this hostname is used for communication. Most people use this default behavior, however, you can specify hostname separately also.